# How can I split a string only when certain exceptions are not present?

Tags: python-3.x

I have managed to create a program that can split strings with a line break based on it containing ". ", "! " and "? ". I have succeeded at this, however I have created a list with exceptions that if those are present in the string it should not include a line break, I just dont know how to read those lists and compare them to the target string to make sure there is no line break.

I am new at programming and at python 3 and have tried creating an additional function called exception_finder that should if it returns True there is no line break, however, this has not succeeded.

```
    sentence= "Hello. My name is George... Michael! Samuel Williams. alittlemouse"
    exception_1_3_char = [". a", ". b", ". c", ". d", ". e", ". f", ". g", ". h", ". i", ". j", ". k", ". l", ". m", ". n", ". o", ". p", ". q", ". r", ". s", ". t", ". u", ". v", ". w", ". x", ". y", ". z"]
    def sentence_splitter(target_sentence):
        target_sentence = list(target_sentence)
        for character in range(len(target_sentence)):
            if target_sentence[character:character+2] == list(". ") or target_sentence[character:character+2] == list("! ") or target_sentence[character:character+2] == list('? ') and exception_finder(target_sentence) == True:
                target_sentence[character:character+2] += list("\n")
                print(''.join(target_sentence))

    sentence_splitter(sentence)

    def exception_finder(target_sentence):
        target_sentence = list(target_sentence)
        for exception in range(len(exception_1_3_char)):
            if exception in target_sentence:
                return True
```

Current Result:

```
    Hello. 
    My name is George... Michael! Samuel Williams. alittlemouse
    Hello. 
    My name is George... 
    Michael! Samuel Williams. alittlemouse
    Hello. 
    My name is George... 
    Michael! 
    Samuel Williams. alittlemouse
    Hello. 
    My name is George... 
    Michael! 
    Samuel Williams. 
    alittlemouse
```

Desired Result:

```
    Hello
    My name is George...
    Michael!
    Samuel Williams. alittlemouse
```

Comment: Line 2 of desired results should be 'My name is George', no? Because '..' is not in the exception list and '.' should be removed after split, just like 'Hello'

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements, you should use Regex and lookahead:

```
import re

sentence= "Hello. My name is George... Michael! Samuel Williams. alittlemouse"
res = re.split('[\.!\?]+(?!\s[a-z])', sentence)
##=> ['Hello', ' My name is George', ' Michael', ' Samuel Williams. alittlemouse']
```

`(?:\s[a-z]\.)` is a negative lookahead, meaning any expression (i.e. `[\.!\?]+`) not followed by `\s[a-z]`. `?!` denotes none capturing group so it will not be captured.

If you only want to split by single '.', you can modify the regex slightly:

```
res = re.split('[\.!\?](?!(?:\s[a-z]|\.))', sentence)
##=> ['Hello', ' My name is George..', ' Michael', ' Samuel Williams. alittlemouse']
```

Comment: How would you modify this to have each element part of the new list, now created by the regular expression, become split into a new line? And furthermore what if you have an exception which is a list of titles such as:
        exception_3a_3_char = ["Dr.", "Jr.", "Mr.", "Ms.", "Sr.", "St."]
How would you use the regular expression for such, more complex exceptions?
By the way, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Now that you have the results in a list, you can print them out however you want to.  As for more complicated cases, it's not uncommon for regex to grow rather long and complex. I don't see anything problem adding more exceptions, such as those in your example, to the expression. You can compose a very complex regex from small pieces. This makes the code cleaner and more robust. If it gets too unwieldy, then you might need to look for alternatives such as specialized parsers.